# Inserting Strings from Java into MySQL. How are datatypes recieved?

Tags: java, mysql, types

I'm parsing through some data all in a text files. By parsing it i throw everything into a String array and then use that array to insert into my MySQL database. Most of the data is actually text strings but some are dates and integers.

If i insert a string like "4538762" into a MySQL column defined as an INT will that be accepted?

Same goes for date.

Comment: How about trying it yourself?

Comment: @pingw33n Yeah i would but its not something i can do at the moment, so i thought posting here would save me a little time.

Comment: What about reading a bit of the [manual, chapter type-conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html)? It would save others a little time.

Comment: @VMai well the data i recieve isnt always consistent. I'm trying to write one parser to work for every text file. So i wouldnt actually know when to cast types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either pass the string as is :

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, "4538762") ;
```

or convert it to int and pass the int :

```
preparedStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt("4538762")) ;
```

MySQL can handle both. In the former case, it would parse the String to int by itself.

Comment: If you can pass strings as is, why would you ever convert it?

Comment: @user3521471 I would convert it myself to check that the string is valid (contains only digits, is not too long, etc...). Otherwise, you would probably get some error from MySQL when running the statement with a string that cannot be converted to an int.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you are running your insert.

You *SHOULD* be running it as a PreparedStatement. When you use prepared statements you add values based on their datatype. See the example below. There is a good tutorial that you should check out at: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html

```
String sql = "update people set firstname=? , lastname=? where id=?";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

preparedStatement.setString(1, "Gary");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "Larson");
preparedStatement.setLong  (3, 123);

int rowsAffected = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Okay so say i have somethign like this: 

preparedStatement.setInt(1, stringArray[0]) is that valid? Sorry i keep pressing enter before i finish typing

Comment: The appropriate way would be ->  preparedStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(stringArray[0])) ;

Comment: Also note that the propearedStatement.setXXX() function is 1-based not 0-based.